# Unable to size a column in CSS to be exactly 50% height

Tags: css

For some reason, I can't use CSS to size the left column to have two exact parts of 50% height.

I've set the height of the div top and bottom to be exact 50%.

The two divs on the left also need to be the exact height of the image on the right.

How can this be done in CSS?

[image]

I'm attempted to do this via the grid. The same problem, when I force the rows to be 50% the text just bleeds outside of the area.

[image]

I've now created a sample code to show the issue

```
    <body>
    <div class="section-8">
        <div class="div-block-230">
            <div class="div-block-233">
                <div>
                    Duis in tellus velit. Mauris vel nunc ac mi imperdiet imperdiet. Suspendisse ultrices Lorem ipsum dolor sit Duis in tellus velit. Mauris vel nunc ac mi imperdiet imperdiet. Suspendisse ultrices Lorem ipsum dolor sitDuis in tellus velit. Mauris vel nunc ac mi imperdiet imperdiet. Suspendisse ultrices Lorem ipsum dolor sitDuis in tellus velit. Mauris vel nunc ac mi imperdiet imperdiet. Suspendisse ultrices Lorem ipsum dolor sitDuis in tellus velit. Mauris vel nunc ac mi imperdiet imperdiet. Suspendisse ultrices Lorem ipsum dolor sitDuis in tellus velit. Mauris vel nunc ac mi imperdiet imperdiet. Suspendisse ultrices Lorem ipsum dolor sit
                    <br/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="div-block-234">
                <div>This is some text inside of a div block.</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="div-block-231"></div>
        <div class="div-block-232"></div>
    </div>       
</body>
```

here is css

```
.div-block-230 {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    width: 40%;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.div-block-231 {
    width: 20%;
    min-height: 300px;
    background-color: #06c;
}

.div-block-232 {
    width: 40%;
}

.div-block-233 {
    height: 50%;
}

.div-block-234 {
    height: 50%;
}
```

As you shrink the browser width, you can see the text in thp box would overflow into the bottom box

Just to clarify the requirements:

1. The two boxes on the left should always be 50/50 split
2. The Image on the right should stretch to accommodate the text height on the left
3. The text on the left should never clip, the box should just enlarge to fit the text

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] in a snippet?  It will make it much easier to troubleshoot your specific issue.

Comment: I added sample code

Answer (score 0):

It can be for many reasons, as the architecture of your Html file for instance. Can you share with us your code (html + css)?

In the meantime, look at the size of your parent tag, he may be adapting its height to its children, which result to this issue (work-around if you need your display to take full screen size: set the parent's height to 100vh)